# How to send selected values

Tags: sql, sql-server

have stored procedure :

```
declare @fistName nvarchar(50) , @lastName nvarchar(50) , @age int , @text nvarchar(max)

SELECT TOP 10  @fistName = fistName , @lastName = lastName , @age = age
FROM users                                                                    

if @age = 18
SELECT @text = 'First Name : ' + @age + CHAR(13) + 'Last Name : ' + @lastName
```

`@text` vallue I sent on my mail. When I select top 1 vallues from my table and age = 18 procedure send me mail, but when I select top 10 vallues and have many first and last names with age 18 , it dont send me mails , any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes! Post the code that you use to send the mails, too. That's my suggestion. Maybe after that you'll get a qualified answer. At a first glance: your're not creating a result set of all entries, but one result set for each entry.

Comment: it's procedure like , `myProc 'ReportName','Subject','Body'`

Comment: For 10 values, does it send mail with data of last member or no mail received??  And you are posting the code where you think the problem is. But the issue may be in some other place. Better paste complete code by hiding you business logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @text = STUFF((
    SELECT TOP 10
        CHAR(13) + 'First Name : ' + fistName + 
        CHAR(13) + 'Last Name : ' + lastName
    FROM dbo.users
    WHERE age = 18
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @text
```